# ApolloClinet (React): How to check if ApolloClient.watchQuery.subscribe.onNext gets called from fetchMore?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I have a query with pagination (so I can't use `fetchPolicy: "no-cache"`) and a subscription. I don't want the subscription to trigger a refetch of the query and reload my component. So I decided to make my own `useQuery` hook by using `useApolloClient()` to get the client and use it's `watchQuery()` method to create an `ObservableQuery` and then use it's `subscribe()` method to react on incoming data.

However I still have the problem of the first callback (`onNext`) being called on Apollo cache update when I only want it run the logic in it when I make the initial query or I call `fetchMore`. **So I need to somehow check if the `onNext` callback is being called by the {initial data return / refetch / etc} or by calling `fetchMore()`** (So I can figure out if I should update the state or not).  *Checking if it's being run for the first time is easy. Just add a state variable that holds the data and set it when `onNext` is called. If the state is already set then the `onNext` is not being run for the first time and can be ignored.*
The problem is that I can't figure a way to check if it's being called by `fetchMore`. From my hook I return the same things that `useQuery` returns:

```
type SmartCacheQueryState<TData = any, TVariables = any> = {
    id: number,
    data?: TData,
    loading: boolean,
    error?: ApolloError,
    networkStatus?: NetworkStatus,
    fetchMore?: (fetchMoreOptions: FetchMoreQueryOptions<TVariables, TData> & FetchMoreOptions<TData, TVariables>) => Promise<ApolloQueryResult<TData>>
}
export function useSmartCacheQuery<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables>(query: DocumentNode | TypedDocumentNode<TData, TVariables>, variables: TVariables): Partial<QueryResult<TData, TVariables>> {
    const apolloClient = useApolloClient()
    const watchQuery = useRef<ObservableQuery<TData, TVariables>>()
    const [returnState, setReturnState] = useState<SmartCacheQueryState>({
        id: Math.random(),
        data: undefined,
        loading: false,
        error: undefined,
        networkStatus: undefined,
        fetchMore: undefined
    })
    const stateRef = useRef<SmartCacheQueryState>(returnState)
    stateRef.current = returnState
    const recieveData = useRef<boolean>(true)

    const [subscribed, setSubscribed] = useState(false)
    if (!returnState.data && !returnState.loading) {
        watchQuery.current = apolloClient.watchQuery({query, variables})
        apolloClient.watchQuery().subscribe(observer)
        if (!subscribed) {
            setSubscribed(true)
            watchQuery.current.subscribe((result: ApolloQueryResult<TData>) => {
                // REPLACE WITH CHECK IF THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED FROM fetchMore()
                if (!recieveData.current)
                    return
                setReturnState((currentState: SmartCacheQueryState) => ({
                    ...currentState,
                    data: result.data,
                    loading: result.loading,
                    error: result.error,
                }))
                recieveData.current = result.data == null
            }, (error) => {
                // onError
            }, () => {
                // onComplete
            })
            setReturnState((currentState: SmartCacheQueryState) => ({
                ...currentState,
                fetchMore: watchQuery.current!.fetchMore.bind(watchQuery.current)
                /*
                fetchMore: (data) => {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    return watchQuery.current!.fetchMore.call(watchQuery.current, data)
                }
                */
            }))
        }
    }
    
    return returnState
}
```

As you see from the commented out line I tried returning a function for `fetchMore` that calls `watchQuery.current!.fetchMore` and returns the result instead of just returning it so I can insert code before calling `fetchMore` on `watchQuery` but it didn't work (`onNext` doesn't get called after `fetchMore`).

*I know there is `query()` method but then I have to merge the data by `fetchMore` manually which is kinda impossible because I don't always know what data comes in. So I'd have to pass a function for merging to my hook and handle the merging from the caller component which I'm trying to avoid.*